# Cant move magento from old server to new server

Tags: magento-1.8, amazon-web-services

I am having a trouble moving the magento from old host to new one.
As a test, I installed fresh magento version and it worked perfectly.

but for moving the server this is what I did:

1. I compressed the folder "www" in the old server
2. I dumped the database from the old server
3. In the new server I downloaded the www file from the old server
4. I imported the database and changed the core_config_data informations (url)
5. I changed the file `local.xml` in `app/etc` folder

No when I start the website it redirects me to the Install page, and the "Welcome to Magento's Installation Wizard!" text is empty, even if I tried to install new version it doesn't work it shows me a blank page when it install the database.

What I am missing, please help.

Comment: check the DB connection is valid.Also check the file permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete or rename `local.xml` to `local.xml.old` in `app/etc` and re-install Magento with your prev. database information